# Sql query to subtract dates and order by hours

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datediff

I have table like this

```
Id  Student     Test_Start          Test_End
1   A       2013-01-08 15:00:17.100     2013-01-08 16:05:55.100 
2   B       2013-02-08 17:01:11.800     2013-02-08 19:05:15.880
3   C       2013-02-08 14:41:10.880     2013-02-08 16:49:22.880
```

What i am trying to do is get Test_End - Test_Start time and change it to hours and display it in ascending order. I have tried:

```
Select convert(date, Test_End) - convert(date,Test_Start) as 'Time_Taken' from students
```

or have tried using DATEDIFF but cant seem to make it work. Is there a best way to accomplish this to show something like this:

```
Time_Taken
1
2
2
```

Comment: Do you want any rounding? e.g. is 15:00 - 16:59:59 one hour or two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
    id,
    student,
    datediff(hour, test_start, test_end) as time_taken
from students
order by time_taken
```

If you want rounding, determine the minutes, add the number of minutes that would be required to round up to the next hour, then divide by 60 to get the rounded hour...

```
select 
    id,
    student,
    (datediff(minute, test_start, test_end) + 30) / 60 as rounded_time_taken
from students
order by rounded_time_taken
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want integer hours?  Under most circumstances, I would rather see the results as fractional hours:

```
select id, student, datediff(s, test_start, test_end)/(60.0*60.0) as hours_taken
from students
order by test_start, test_end)/(60.0*60.0)
```